# Link not firing inside Bootstrap sortable li

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, event-handling, event-listener

I have a sortable list of Django objects inside a Bootstrap tab, with links inside each element. The links, when clicked, do nothing. There's no behavior whatsoever, as if you clicked plain text. When hovering, the cursor does change, but otherwise it acts like it's not a link.

I've implemented this before, but with buttons instead of li's, and had no trouble with the links there. I've confirmed that the view and URLs work just fine, by placing them on other pages in normal links.

There's an event listener - `keydown` at `jquery.js:4334` - which, if killed from the developer tools, seems to fix the issue. I don't know what this is, how it's started up, or what the other consequences are of killing it.

Code for the tab containing the links: (the ones to `benchmarks:questionremove`)

```
<div role="tabpanel"  class="tab-pane" data-toggle="tab" id="questions" href="#questions">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Sortable photos
    // jQuery and jQuery-UI are in base.html
    console.log('starting')
    var teacherid = "{{this_teacher.pk}}";
    var sectionid = "{{this_section.pk}}";
    var adminid = "{{this_admin.pk}}";
    var benchmarkid = "{{this_benchmark.pk}}";



    // using jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue =   decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    var baseUrl=document.location.href.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/')+'/benchmarks/';
    console.log(baseUrl+teacherid+"-"+sectionid+"-"+adminid+"-"+benchmarkid+"/sort");
    console.log("token",csrftoken)

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }



      $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
          var serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');

      $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+teacherid+"-"+sectionid+"-"+adminid+"-"+benchmarkid+"/sort",
        type: "post",
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
              jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
        data: serial
      });
        },
      }).disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
  {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="admin container" style="padding-top:8px; padding-left:6px;">

      <div class="panel-group" style="width:100%;">
        {% if question_list %}
        {% csrf_token %}
          <ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">

            {% for question in question_list %}
              <li id="question_{{ question.pk }}" class="ui-state-default" style='background-color:#ffffff;'>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" style="left-padding:-2px;"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span style="float:right;"><a href={% url 'benchmarks:questionremove' Question_id=question.pk %} >
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
                </a>
                {{ question.Number}} {{question.Text}}
              </li>

            {% endfor %}
          </ul>

        {% else %}
          ...

        {% endif %}
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: See my if solution helps..

Comment: I'd also accept answers giving more understanding about possible causes of links being recognized but not firing, about event listeners (and that one in particular), and anything else that gets at possible root causes.

Comment: To be clear for folks finding this question later: Neither of the answers below fix the issue. The dragula suggestion streamlines things somewhat, but has no effect, and the `""` suggestion for the template tag href is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Simple advice here: from experience I find out that jQuery UI is a PITA with this kind of issues (mostly because it relies heavily on default CSS classes and properties).

So from now on I'm using dragula for drag-n-drop actions, its syntax is starightforward with VanillaJS and your example would be something like:

```
dragula([document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li')]).on('dragend', function() {
    var serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');

    $.ajax({
      url: baseUrl+teacherid+"-"+sectionid+"-"+adminid+"-"+benchmarkid+"/sort",
      type: "post",
      beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
          jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      },
      data: serial
    });
  },
}).on('selectstart', function(){ return false; });
```

and some `user-select: none` for disabling selection.

Demo and docs: https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Comment: Interesting solution - thanks for the link and example. It does work to execute the sorting, but I still can't use the links.

Comment: Then I would suggest using a handle for your element `dragula([document.querySelectorAll('#sortable li')], {
          moves: function (el, container, handle) {
            return handle.classList.contains('glyphicon-resize-vertical');
          }
        })`

Comment: Another thing, you HTML seems broken: the structure is `<span><a><span></span></span></a> `also, you may want to avoid floating left

Comment: Broken how? I'm not seeing that

Comment: Gotcha - I simplified the html structure, putting the float inside the `a` tag; no effect on the issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a missing `" "` wrapping around your `href` value

```
<a href={% url 'benchmarks:questionremove' Question_id=question.pk %} >
```

Change it to this

```
<a href="{% url 'benchmarks:questionremove' Question_id=question.pk %}" >
```

Also your current HTML is not formatted properly..

```
  <span style="float:right;">
      <a href={% url 'benchmarks:questionremove' Question_id=question.pk %} >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </span>
     </a>
```

Structure is along with the above mentioned `" "` and your final HTML must look like..

```
  <span style="float:right;">
      <a href="{% url 'benchmarks:questionremove' Question_id=question.pk %}">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
  </span>
```

Comment: These links work: `<a style="float:right;" href={% url 'benchmarks:rosterremove' Student_id=student.pk  %} >`, `<a href={% url 'gbook:doedit' to_edit='ass' pk=assessment.pk Course_id=this_course.pk Section_id=active_section.pk %} class="pointerhover announce">`, so I don't think that the quotation marks around the template tag are correct.